# Get QListWidgetItem deleted when it's itemWidget get closed

Tags: qt4, qt4.8

Is it possible to let `QListWidget` remove a `QListWidgetItem`, when the widget (I use `setItemWidget()`) gets `closed()`?

For now I pass in the row number and signal back to the main window, which will delete the item by row, but that sounds stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want delete all items on QListWidget.close()? Let's try this

```
list = MyListWidget.items();
qDeleteAll(list.begin(), list.end());
list.clear();
```

in closeEvent(). Must create your own widget from QListWidget to reimplement|use protected methods.